# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, list, foreach

I have a list of objects and I need to iterate over the list and add a certain property (string) from the object to a map of <string, boolean>. Here is my code:

```
this.selectedPeople.forEach(element => {
  this.checkedPeople.set(element.name, true);
}
```

The purpose of this is to set checkboxes to be checked for certain people (if they are in the selectedPeople list) using `[checked]` in Angular. For some reason, I get this error when trying to build the project:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'
```

I tried to change `element.name` to just `element` and that provides errors during compilation but when I look at the frontend, none of the checkboxes are checked (as you would expect since the key in the map is not a string as required). I have done similar things with other lists and they seem to be working fine, so why is this an issue here?

Edit1: I have seen some other solutions on here but they do not seem to be relevant to my case or have not worked.

Edit2: This is not the actual code as it is company code so I have tried to recreate the issue using a different scenario so as not to run into any confidentiality issues. To elaborate further, the selectedPeople array would be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Paul",
    "age":24,
    "sport":"Football"
  },
  {
    "name":"Tom",
    "age":22,
    "sport":"Tennis"
  }
]
```

Edit3: For further clarification, here is what my `checkedPeople` map looks like:

```
0: {"Paul" => false}
1: {"Jennifer" => false}
2: {"Georgia" => false}
3: {"Tom" => false}
```

And I am trying to change the value to true for each person who is in the selectedPeople array.

Comment: Can you write a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and possibly include a [TS PLayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) link showcasing the issue?

Comment: `element` isn't what you expect it to be, please edit your question with the data you're trying to use. Also, `foreach` is misspelled, should be `forEach`.

Comment: Can you show the code where `this.selectedPeople` is populated?

Comment: @Phix I've made edits to best reflect the data I am working with (also, the forEach typo was only in the question and was typed correctly in the code so that shouldn't be the problem but thank you for pointing it out). What do you mean by ```element``` isn't what I expect it to be?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery so it's populated using an API call to the backend but I have made an edit to show what the data ```this.selectedPeople``` looks like in the frontend using ```JSON.stringify()```.

Comment: Did you log the result of the API call to confirm that that's actually what it looks like? Because if that's what the array actually contains, then it should work.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yes, I have logged it and used a debugger to check the value both before entering the forEach loop and for each element in the forEach loop. I also use the results of the API call for the rest of my program and everything works fine as expected.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed some of your comments on the answers, sounds like you're using TypeScript, not JavaScript. The problem might be in how you're declaring the type of the `selectedPeople` property in that case.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery that's what I thought but I use it in multiple other places and it works as expected. Also, I used typeof on the properties within the objects and again, everything is as it should be.

Comment: `typeof` looks at what the actual type is, not what you told TypeScript it is. From the other comments it sounds like you might have accidentally made it a `string[]` but it's impossible to say without seeing how you declared it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using `element['name']` instead of `element.name` and that seemed to do the trick. I do not quite understand why this works (especially given that `element.name` is used elsewhere and works fine) so if anyone has any idea, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your project setup, I'm betting that typescript thinks that `element` can be a string or an object... something like this:

```
type SelectedPeople = Array<string | { name: string }>
```

In such as case, you will need to make sure the item is not a string before accessing the `name` property:

```
this.selectedPeople.foreach(element => {
  if(typeof element === 'string') {
     this.checkedPeople.set(element, true);
  } else {
    this.checkedPeople.set(element.name, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have just tried this and now get an error saying "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can either try what Ryan is suggesting above, or alternatively you can add a safe check before setting each element like so:

```
this.selectedPeople.forEach(element => {

If (element && element.Name){
  this.checkedPeople.set(element.name, true);
 }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still gives the same error (as does Ryan's )

Comment: Sounds to me that the issue is in the way you are fetching your data then

Comment: A few people suggested that but I have logged the response and used selectedPeople elsewhere and everything is working as expected. It's just this that causes any issues